# CakePHP 3.x -> belongs to Many for theree tables

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a setup where the relationship is three factors:

member
group
role

So a member may be part of multiple groups (and groups contain multiple members), but depending on that combination, the role will also differ.

A database person at work told me to set up the tables like this:

```
member
id name

group
id name

role
id name

member_group_role
id member_id group_id role_id
```

How do I get this to work with cakephp?  I have successfully set up HABTM for only two linked tables but not three.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to your structure what i think there are 4 models one for each table.
First 3 models will relates with 4th model as `hasMany` and 4th model will relate with these models as `BelongsTo` like

1) Member

```
class MemberTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->hasMany('MemberHasGroupHasRole')
            ->setForeignKey('member_id');
    }
}
```

2) Group

```
class GroupTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->hasMany('MemberHasGroupHasRole')
            ->setForeignKey('group_id');
    }
}
```

3) Role

```
class RoleTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->hasMany('MemberHasGroupHasRole')
            ->setForeignKey('role_id');
    }
}
```

4) MemberHasGroupHasRole

```
class MemberHasGroupHasRoleTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsTo('Member')
            ->setForeignKey('member_id')
            ->setJoinType('INNER');

        $this->belongsTo('Group')
            ->setForeignKey('group_id')
            ->setJoinType('INNER');

        $this->belongsTo('Role')
            ->setForeignKey('role_id')
            ->setJoinType('INNER');
    }
}
```

Comment: So I tried this but cakephp is telling me that Members is not associated with Roles.

Comment: Member is not directly associated with role, member is indirectly associated with role via junction MemberHasGroupHasRoleTable  model, like to load roles you need to eager load it as `MemberHasGroupHasRole.Role` [reference](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#eager-loading-associations)